# Sign Up for an ISV Partner Account in the Partner Community

Tags: community, partner

I am trying to sign-up to the [Partner Community](http://partnersignup.salesforce.com/) to get an ISV Partner Account

I filled all the needed data

But I am getting this error about my email

> Please correct the following error(s):
>
> This email domain is restricted from signing up for our Partner Program.

[image: Error]

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partner Community sign up requires you to use corporate email address .Signing using gmail or yahoo mail or outlook will is not allowed .Only way i have managed to get access to a partner community is by using a corporate email .

Comment: So we can't put an app on the AppExchange store as a freelancer :( ?

Comment: You can but you need to create a business mailId .There are plenty that can provide a business mail account for very low price .I know few like https://www.bluehost.com/ and https://www.name.com/email .They all cost very less .If you have your own domain its not hard to sign up for a business email .The other approach is obviously reach out to salesforce and ask them for an emailId .I am sure they would provide you one .

Comment: You can use @googlemail.com which bypasses the validation.